# Inline code not rendered correctly in rendered output diff on suggested edit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, diff

[This suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27319294) on Stack Overflow only removes excess indentation from code, as shown in the markdown diff:

[image: screenshot of markdown diff]

However, the rendered output diff shows a newline being removed before ‘Sample output’ and inline code formatting is not rendered correctly:

[image: screenshot of rendered output diff]